# Cannot Change the boot order in bios or F9 Anymore after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

other Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 (64-bit)
hi
I have a **HP Pavilion TS Sleekbook 15 touchsmart** 
I cannot change the boot order in the bios boot order menu ( i tried **to disable the legacy boot didnt help**)
**F5 F6 buttons dont work.**
when i press them the display **blinds** but the boot order doesnt move or change.
also I had been able to use the F9 button when start up
but after that I insalled ubuntu there **doesnt show up the USB boot option in the F9 menu anymore** .
there is **[full of ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfSz.jpg)** ubuntu ubuntu ubuntu as you may see on the picture.

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment, I suspect you may have something left over on your [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) Mount it and, if Ubuntu is no longer installed, delete the `EFI/ubuntu` directory tree. You may also need to delete `EFI/BOOT` -- but it may hold Windows files, so that could help or make things worse.

You can mount the ESP in Windows by opening an *Administrator* Command Prompt window and typing `mountvol S: /S` (you can change `S:` to another drive identifier if you like). The ESP will then be mounted at `S:`, but only for that specific Command Prompt window.

Comment: Dual-boot Repair tool automatically mounts ESP on start (download from http://www.boyans.net). Using dialog for "Backup BCD" you can freely browse ESP (usually mapped to drive Z:) with administrative rights so you can edit any file or delete whole directories (\EFI\ubuntu as Rod Smith already pointed as probable cause for reloading Ubuntu NVRAM boot entry)

Comment: The most secure way for editing NVRAM is using firmware capabilities. There should be an option to delete boot entries or reorder them. From Windows the utility bcdedit.exe should be able to delete NVRAM boot entries - list firmware boot loaders and select Ubuntu loader for deletion by GUID ( bcdedit /delete {GUID_of_Ubuntu_loader} )

Comment: If you understand this question @Rob, can you please explain to me what `the display blinds` means?  There is much to fix in this question -- might you edit it to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed ubuntu in the Wrong partition(which is C: drive).

**To confirm:** Boot your ubuntu os and search for directory which have folders below.(perflog, Program files, Users, Windows)

[image: widnows c]

If no, you need to install windows Operating system again.

if yes, start your ubuntu os and follow this http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-boot-order-of-a-dual-boot-linux-pc/ and select windows os.

Comment: hi I solved this problem with an another way before I saw your comment, thank you very much, I used the freeware software named visual bcd and deleted all ubuntus from the bcd list, but every time when I run the windows it adds there one more ubuntu even I havent got the ubuntu anymore :)

Comment: you need to format your system to remove all ubuntu :)