# Dual boot- Windows 8.1+Ubuntu 14.04.3->Not getting dual boot option

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Windows 8.1 and wanted dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04.3.I followed the steps from [this site](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) and installed Ubuntu.I restarted my laptop and and I'm not getting dualboot option,it gets straight to Ubuntu. How can i fix that?

Comment: Try opening a terminal `ctrl`+`alt`+`t` and running `sudo update-grub`. Let that return to a prompt and then reboot. See if Windows shows up now.

Comment: **Comment :**  see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/730166/cannot-change-the-boot-order-in-bios-or-f9-anymore-after-installing-ubuntu/730180#730180

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu)